# Renaming database prefix to always be previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms-2012

I'm using SSMS 2012 and trying to figure out a way to write a query so that my database name will adjust to the second to most current month.

We have billing databases for every month that go like `BillingMonth01206` and `BillingMonth022016`, as well as one called `BillingMonthLM` for "Last Month".  The LM database is nice as we do not have to constantly change databases for last month's data, but I always need the one before that.  So as it is now September, I need July billing (BillingMonth072016).

I have been doing a find and replace every month, but is there a way to automatically configure this?  Maybe using a string or something?

Comment: You should load the data into a single reporting database/table and not much around with renaming databases.  You'll end up with problems anyway, because you probably need to rename the underlying files as well.

Comment: Database name shouldn't change.  I can see where you might move off monthly snapshots for reporting, but the database should not be so transient.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses.  The underlying tables are the same in each database, so no tables names are affected.  I just need to reference a different database each month.  I cannot change the structure of the server, or the databases, so this is my only option.

Comment: It is better to use YYYYMM format (201607).

Comment: You can automate find and replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DECLARE  
       @Month varchar(2)
      ,@Year varchar(4)
      ,@SQL varchar(max)
      ,@DataBaseName varchar(50)

 SET @Month = CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()))
 SET @Year = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE())

 IF (LEN(@Month) = 1)
      SET @Month = '0' + @Month

 SET @DataBaseName = 'BillingMonth' + @Month + @Year

 SET @SQL = 'ALTER DATABASE BillingMonth072016  
             Modify Name = ' + @DataBaseName + '' 

 EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: If you play around with this query you might be able to achieve what you want, but you will have to have Alter permissions on databases.